# What is the difference between WP: template_directory vs TEMPLATEPATH

Tags: theme-development

I am trying to code in more consistent manner and would like to know what is the difference between WP: template_directory vs TEMPLATEPATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tanktery

`template_directory` is the **URL** of the active theme's directory. Before version 2.6 of WordPress it was a local path.

`TEMPLATEPATH`is also the **URL** of the active theme's directory.

Before version 2.6 `TEMPLATEPATH` was used but now it is recommended to use `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/about.txt'); ?>
How would I use <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>?

Comment: Actually, the correct functions to use are `get_template_directory_uri()` (for the URL to the *template*, i.e. *Parent Theme*, directory), and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` (for the URL to the *Theme's* directory).

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo TEMPLATEPATH; ?>/about.txt">About</a>` would be `<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/about.txt">About</a>`